# Bind a docker container to a single network interface

Tags: docker, vlan

Currently my home network is logically segmented in 2 separate VLANS.

- **LAN** (untagged native LAN `10.20.0.0/16`): where all the trusted devices will operate
- **IOT_LAN** (with tag 30 `10.30.0.0/16`): where all the IOT/home entertainment untrusted devices will operate.

At firewall level `LAN` can access `IOT_LAN` but not viceversa.

I'm running **Docker** on a raspberry pi 4 connected via ethernet cable to a trunk port of my switch. At Raspi level, the Native LAN is bound to the `eth0` interface while `IOT_LAN` is bound to `eth0.30`.

The question here is: is it possible to have 2 different containers running at the same time one bound to the eth0 interface and the other bound to eth0.30?

For sake of example we can say container 1 is an application which needs to be able to access  the main `LAN` network and container 2 is an IOT specific app which I want to be restricted to the `IOT_LAN` network.

Thank you

Comment: Yes; the `docker run -p` and Docker Compose `ports:` option let you specify a host IP address to bind to.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, I've tried that option without any luck. The container is still able to ping devices on `LAN` network

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue:

I've created a network in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
# IOT_LAN.
networks:
  vlan30:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0.30
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.30.0.0/16
```

Each container which needs to stay in the 10.30 network is then attached to the network above using the following syntax:

```
networks:
  vlan30:
    ipv4_address: "10.30.0.15"
```

The IP address gets defined in the docker-compose file and should belong to a reserved range previously created on the router to avoid collision with DHCP assigned addresses.

This worked for me. All the container now belong only to `10.30` network.

Comment: I get "ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space"